# Error setting state when getting data from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to load a list of 'Posts' from my firebase database into my react app. Specifically trying to set the state of my posts array.

```
constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.grabPosts()
    }

    grabPosts = () => {
        const postList = firebase.db('posts').on('value', function(snapshot) {

            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                console.log(child.val())

                //Get child data
                const childPost = child.val()

                //Get copy of current state
                const currentState = this.state.posts

                //Push item into array
                const newState = currentState.push(childPost)

                //Update state
                this.setState({
                    tasks: newState
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

Firebase Structure

```
posts
   - (id)
      - post-title
      - post-image
      ..... etc etc
```

Im just trying to build an array of post objects so i can map through and create components for each post. However everytime I attempt to change my state I recieve the same error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on where/how I am supposed to set the state of my posts

Comment: use this: `firebase.db('posts').on('value', (snapshot) => {....}`

Comment: that worked, knew I was close. Have to look into arrow functions again to get a deeper understanding. Thanks!